# How to drag file on OS X without having to click it twice

Tags: mojave, trackpad

I'm running Mojave 10.14.6.

On previous version of OS X, I could click and drag files same as on other OSs. However, with this version, by default it had the 3-finger drag, which I disabled by un-checking `Enable Dragging`. Now when I try to click and drag a file, nothing happens. I need to click to select the file, at which point its highlit, and THEN I can click and drag it.

Does anyone know how I can configure my system so that I can just click and drag files without having to pre-click to select the file first?

Comment: I checked three different Macs. None exhibit this, so I would guess the real problem you’ve got  is what modification [on your system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/162715/) has changed [the default behaviors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/). Have you made a new user account to rule out some setting or software your main user runs? It could be accessibility setting like here; https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173832/macbook-trackpad-tap-to-drag-issues

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is you have Accessibility options you don’t like enabled.

- [Unable to double tap on the trackpad to highlight multiple words in macOS Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348706/unable-to-double-tap-on-the-trackpad-to-highlight-multiple-words-in-macos-mojave)
- [What's the difference between one finger dragging and drag lock?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/whats-the-difference-between-one-finger-dragging-and-drag-lock)